# Swift unwrapping optional giving error with data

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

My iOS application fetch data from server and render some images from that data using 'Kingfisher', the problem is whenever i add or replace new image on server application crashes due to this code below with error :
"***fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value***"

```
let prfix:String = "MY_PREFIX_URL /\(org.image)"
celImage.kf_setImageWithURL((NSURL(string: prfix))!)
```

Please check the sceeenshot for more detail[image: error screenshot] 
I don't undestand why I am getting this error, because you can see `prfix` got a value.

Comment: Please post full image url. It's safe :)

Comment: The best approach is to pull the line apart;  assign your `NSURL` to a variable.Check if it is nil.  If it is, look closely at the URL.  Why is it nil?  If it isn't nil, what is?  Is `org.title` nil?  Set a breakpoint. Single step to see what is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its due to `prefix` contain with unnecessary characters, you can fix this with `URLHostAllowedCharacterSet`

You can fix `prefix` malformed url like this (swift 2.x).

```
let urlStr : NSString = prfix.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(.URLHostAllowedCharacterSet())!

celImage.kf_setImageWithURL((NSURL(string: urlStr as String))!)
```

this will make sure the url contains only good string.

Comment: `MY_PREFIX_URL` can contain _more_ than just the host component. For example: `https://user:password@www.example.com/path/`. So, your approach would not work reliable.

Comment: This will work. But in case of bad URLs, it will return blank image. The best approach is as Paulw11 has mentioned in his comment. assign to NSURL, do a nil check. If fails, assign your placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

`NSURL(string:)` is a failable initialiser and can then return `nil` if your `string` parameter is not a valid URL, as you can read in the documentation of NSURL:

`Initialize a NSURLComponents with a URL string. If the URLString is malformed, nil is returned.`

You have to check your final URL integrity because apparently it is malformed...